# springbatch program does not end gracefully after batch job is completed

Tags: spring-batch, hikaricp

I have a simple springbatch which reads data from DB and writes to eventhub.I use HikariCP to connect to DB. My batch does not end gracefully after job is complete. Somehow HikariCP reinitializes on its own.

```
11:32:55.151 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
11:32:55.193 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
11:32:55.194 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager - Acquired Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1438178266 wrapping ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: ef2e5d07-0aed-417e-a571-2c9fec2fdf34] for JDBC transaction
11:32:55.194 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switching JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1438178266 wrapping ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: ef2e5d07-0aed-417e-a571-2c9fec2fdf34] to manual commit
11:32:55.236 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
11:32:55.236 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM dse.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
11:32:55.275 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
11:32:55.275 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dse.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
11:32:55.303 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL update
11:32:55.303 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE dse.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?,  STATUS = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, CREATE_TIME = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
11:32:55.339 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
11:32:55.339 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1438178266 wrapping ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: ef2e5d07-0aed-417e-a571-2c9fec2fdf34]
11:32:55.446 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1438178266 wrapping ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: ef2e5d07-0aed-417e-a571-2c9fec2fdf34] after transaction
11:32:55.447 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=migrateEmailJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=34}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
11:33:19.316 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
11:33:49.319 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
11:34:19.323 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)

<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
   <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
   <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do you use a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` (or have it defined as a bean in your application context)? Hikari should not prevent the JVM from exiting. There should be something else that needs to to be stopped.

Comment: No I do not use ThreadPoolTaskExecutor explicitly.

Comment: Even if you don't use it explicitly, you need to shut it down after your job. Otherwise, your JVM will not exit.

Answer (score 2):

Did a workaround as below.

```
    public class JobCompletionNotificationListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {

     @Override
        public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
            if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
                   new Thread(() -> {
                    try {
                        houseKeeping.clean();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }

//method in the housekeeping class.

public void clean() throws Exception {
        log.info("Initiate Housekeeping Task");
        Thread.sleep(delayTime);
        jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().close();
        eventHubClient.close();
        configurableApplicationContext.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the added value of getting a new connection and closing it right after. If you have a db connection you want to close, keep a reference to it and close it in the `clean` method. Moreover, using `System.exit` will not let your JVM exit gracefully, you need to remove it IMO. Same for closing the application context, you need to let Spring close the context (properly dispose other beans your job is using). A last point, I would not start a thread after job completion and make it sleep for some delay, you can call the `clean` method in the current thread.

Comment: In sum, I think your `afterJob` method should only contain `eventHubClient.close();`. I guess this is what preventing your JVM from exiting (besides the eventual `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` bean that you need to shutdown if it is defined you application context **even if you don't use it explicitly**. Hope this helps!

Comment: Realized I sent it soon. Without System.exit() , hikari pool does not shutdown and hence program hangs.

Comment: Shutting down eventHubClient  and ThreadPoolTaskExecutor still keeps HikariCP running.

Comment: 08:01:09.882 [Thread-16] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'.08:01:35.157 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=20, active=0, idle=20, waiting=0)